# Am I getting a sandbox certificate when I try to generate a production APNS certificate?

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I have an existing app using push notifications.  Inspecting the current certificate shows `Apple Production IOS Push Sercies:...` for the CN.  On the new cert, it only says "Apple Push Services:...".

This is what the web site looks like upon creating the certificate:
[image]

When I connect to the APNS service to send a push notification, I get the following message:

*You have selected the Production server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Production certificate!  Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!*

If the certificates are being generated now the same way they were a year ago, it seems like I am getting the wrong certificate even though I have the "Production SSL" radio button selected.

Comment: I did notice the documentation for APNS Notes HTTP2 now, so it could be possible that HTTP2 is not required and our APNS client needs to be updated.

Comment: Did you install new client SSL certificate ?

Comment: Is there something additional I need to install on the APNS server other than the  APNS cert itself?